# XSLT Apply Templates to derive specific parent & children records, children can be parent too

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need help with my XSLT. Here's my XML structure.

```
<root>
<row>
    <component>mainfield_1</component>
    <type>Field</type>
    <where_used>
        <component>subfield_2</component>
        <type>Field</type>
    </where_used>
    <where_used>
        <component>report_1</component>
        <type>Report</type>
    </where_used>
</row>
<row>
    <component>subfield_2</component>
    <type>Field</type>
    <where_used>
        <component>report_2</component>
        <type>report</type>
    </where_used>
</row>
<row>
    <component>mainfield_3</component>
    <type>Field</type>
</row>
</root>
```

I would like it to be transformed into the following:

```
<root>
<row>
    <component>mainfield_1</component>
    <type>Field</type>
</row>
<row>
    <component>subfield_2</component>
    <type>Field</type>
</row>
<row>
    <component>report_1</component>
    <type>Report</type>
</row>
<row>
    <component>report_2</component>
    <type>report</type>
</row>
</root>
```

Basically, I am trying to get all the distinct dependencies of component mainfield_1. Here's my sample code but it is not enough to find any matching parent that has the same component name as the children.

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row[component='mainfield_1']"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <component>
            <xsl:value-of select="component"/>
        </component>
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="type" />
        </type>
    </row>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="where_used"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="where_used">
    <row>
        <component>
            <xsl:value-of select="component"/>
        </component>
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="type" />
        </type>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

If I run the above, I will not be able to get this.

```
<row>
  <component>report_2</component>
  <type>report</type>
</row>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a key to look up the `row` items by `component`

```
<xsl:key name="rows" match="row" use="component" />
```

Then you can have a template for `where_used` nodes that refer to a separate row, allowing you to select that row instead

```
<xsl:template match="where_used[key('rows', component)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('rows', component)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="rows" match="row" use="component" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row[component='mainfield_1']"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* except where_used" />
        </row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="where_used"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="where_used">
        <row>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </row>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="where_used[key('rows', component)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('rows', component)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have used the identity template too, to avoid having to explicitly copy existing nodes that don't need to be changed.